# program crashes with c0000374

Tags: c++

visual studio also gives these warning. Buffer overrun while writing to 'array1':  the writable size is '1*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written. Buffer overrun while writing to 'array2 ':  the writable size is '1*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int charCountForA1, charCountForA2;

    cout << "How many character do you want for Array 1 ? ";
    cin >> charCountForA1;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "How many character do you want for Array 2 ? ";
    cin >> charCountForA2;

    //dynamic declaration of memory
    double* array1 = new double(charCountForA1);
    double* array2 = new double(charCountForA2);

    cout << endl;

    //to get user inputs to fill the array 1
    for (int n = 0; n < charCountForA1; n++) {

        double x;
        cout << "Enter the element for index " << n << " of Array 1: ";
        cin >> x;
        array1[n] = x;

    }

    cout << endl;

    //to get user inputs to fill the array 1
    for (int n = 0; n < charCountForA2; n++) {

        double x;
        cout << "Enter the element for index " << n << " of Array 2: ";
        cin >> x;
        array2[n] = x;

    }
```

Comment: `double* array1 = new double(charCountForA1);` -- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `double* array1 = new double(charCountForA1);` --> `std::vector<double> array1(charCountForA1);`  The same thing for the other line of code.

Comment: If the answer below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: BTW `0xC0000374` is STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55

Answer (score 5):

The lines

```
    double* array1 = new double(charCountForA1);
    double* array2 = new double(charCountForA2);
```

are not allocating arrays but allocating single `double` initialized to `charCountForA1` and `charCountForA2`.

Use `[]` instead of `()` to allocate arrays.

```
    double* array1 = new double[charCountForA1];
    double* array2 = new double[charCountForA2];
```

Comment: Ending with a recommendation for using `std::vector` would help complete this answer.